# CMS with AJAX admin panel

Tags: ajax, web-applications, content-management-system

I have quite an old CMS which is approaching the phase of full redesign.
Currently I'd like to review some ready-made CMS-es for their admin panels made in full AJAX.
Can anyone suggest something for a start?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out VAACO, the whole admin panel is just one webpage with AJAX calls.

http://florida.vaaco.com/admin

```
username: admin
password: demo123
```